# Should I pay any notice to this log event?

Tags: apache-2.2, logging

for some reason I keep on getting the following log event repeatedly in my apache logs:

```
Jun 11 20:48:59 ruby apache_cvrugby_access_rsys: 77.78.104.50 - - [11/Jun/2013:20:48:58 -0400] "GET /server-status HTTP/1.0" 200 306923 "-" "-"
```

(with different times, etc, same ip though)

here is a screenshot of what I am talking about, though this has been going on all day so there is much more than what is shown:
[image]

Should I be worried about such activity (person sending requests may be up to no good, etc), or is this normal behavior? This is the first time I've seen such a thing in my logs. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have `mod_status` enabled?

If so, are remote devices allowed to access it without authentication?

If so.. yeah, that's a bad thing.  Look for a `SetHandler server-status` line in your configuration - access to that needs to be locked down.

Comment: Thanks! Had checked out the settings and think I have things squared away, have this friendly sight in my error logs now too haha http://i.imgur.com/I5vh6dV.png, may just block his ip completely though if he keeps it up at this rate for more than a few days